# Start string with '(quotes) and terminate with $txt$ in postgresql

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, sql-injection

I have an PHP application with some security schemas, to prevent SQL Injection the programers using PHP pg_scape_string. I'm a security analyst and my work is broken this schemas. I need find a way to pass the quotes.

For example: 
In a sql command: 
`select * from table where field = $par and two=$par2;`

The SQL inject: 
`select * from owner.table where field = '0' or 1=1;--' and two=value;`

With pg_scape_string in sql command: 
`select * from owner.table where varcharfield = '0'' or 1=1;--' and two=value;`

How can i close the `where field = '0` without quotes?

Comment: Why do you have a problem with quotes? The alternatives would be much more complicated and error-prone.

Comment: because in the SQL atack, i cannot use the quotes, the security schema don't let it pass.

Comment: I'd say that you should get a less benighted security tool. Writing a function that properly dollar quotes your strings adds complexity, which is bad for security. Is using prepared statements an option?